# Theanoのscan関数のoutput_infoについて http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/rbm.html

Tags: python, 機械学習

http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/rbm.html
このページでRBMについて学んでいるのですが、get_cost_update関数の中で使われるscanのoutputs_infoがなぜ

> outputs_info=[None, None, None, None, None, chain_start]

となっているのかわかりません。
NoneをChain_startの前に5つ並べたのには何か意味があるのでしょうか。
また、このときどのような挙動をするかについても教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: コメントに "the None are **place holders**, saying that chain_start is the initial state corresponding to the 6th output" と書かれてある通りかと思いますが。。。

Comment: ごめんなさい、つまりどういう意図でこの形になってるんでしょうか...